# Calculate the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{4^x - \sqrt{1-x}}{x^2\ln(1+e^{1/x})}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, solution-verification

The problem is stated as:

> Calculate $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{4^x - \sqrt{1-x}}{x^2\ln(1+e^{1/x})}$ using L'Hospital's rule.

**My attempt:**

In order to use L'Hospital, we have to check whether we have a $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ - case.

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{4^x - \sqrt{1-x}}{x^2\ln(1+e^{1/x})}$

The numerator clearly tends to $0$, so we have to check whether the denominator does so too.

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}{x^2\ln(1+e^{1/x})} = \frac{\ln(1+e^{1/x})}{1/x^2}$ which is a $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ - case. Hence, using L'Hopsital and simplifying, we have:

$\frac{xe^{1/x}}{e^{1/x}+1}=\frac{x}{1+e^{-1/x}} \rightarrow 0$ as $ x \rightarrow 0^{+}$

So, we can apply L'H for our given limit, as we have a $0/0$ case, so applying L'H, we get:

$\frac{4^x\ln(4)+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-x}}}{2x\ln(1+e^{1/x})-\frac{e^{1/x}}{1+e^{1/x}}}$

Let $x \rightarrow 0^{+}$, we then finally get:

$2x\ln(1+e^{1/x}) = 2\ln(1+e^{1/x})/{(1/x)}$, which gives us a $\infty / \infty$ - case as $x\rightarrow 0^{+} $ , applying L'H we get:

$\frac{-2e^{1/x}/(x^2(1+e^{1/x}))}{-1/x^2} = 2\frac{e^{1/x}}{1+e^{1/x}} \rightarrow 2$ as $x\rightarrow 0^{+} $.

Similarly, we get that $\frac{e^{1/x}}{1+e^{1/x}} \rightarrow 1$ as $x\rightarrow 0^{+}$.

Altogether we have:

$$\boxed{
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{4^x - \sqrt{1-x}}{x^2\ln(1+e^{1/x})} = \frac{\ln(4)+1/2}{2-1}=\ln(4)+1/2}$$

---

I hope some of you can check whether my procedure is correct. I actually didn't solve it at first and I wanted to ask for tips to move on, but I somehow managed to figure out what to do in order to finish the problem while writing this question :)

Thank you!

Comment: Use `$\ln x$` for $\ln x$.

Comment: @Shaun, Thank you, I'll correct it.

Comment: It is correct, although it's not the simplest approach.

Comment: $ln(1+e^{1/x})\approx ln(e^{1/x})=\frac{1}{x}$  Also $4^x=e^{xln(4)}\approx 1+xln(4)$ and $\sqrt{1-x}\approx 1-\frac{x}{2}$.  Putting it together, expression $\approx \frac {x(ln(4)+\frac{1}{2})}{x}$.

Comment: @Matteo I haven't heard of asymptotic relations before, but as something extra to learn I'd be pleased if you posted your solution with some explanations about how it all works. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is correct. Alternatively, this is how you could proceed without having to use L'Hospital's rule:

$$\frac{4^x - \sqrt{1-x}}{x^2\ln(1+e^{1/x})}=\left(\frac{4^x -1}x+\color{blue}{\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x}}{x}} \right)\frac 1{x\ln(1+e^\frac 1x)}=\left(\frac{4^x -1}x+\color{blue}{\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1-x}}} \right)\frac 1{x\ln(1+e^\frac 1x)}$$

Note that the standard limit $\frac {4^x-1}{x}\to \log 4$ and that  $\frac 1{x\ln(1+e^\frac 1x)}=\frac 1{1+x\ln\left(1+\frac 1{e^\frac 1x}\right)}\to1$ as $x\to 0+$ (because $\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac 1{e^\frac 1x}= 0$ hence the denominator has limit $1+0=1$.)

So the required limit is: $\log 4+\frac 12$